# input string to function from another file

Tags: php, html, string, function, echo

i dont think my title is right becuase i have no way to explain it when writing. I will try my best to show what i want to do.

i Have a function called get_footer which is like this:

```
function get_footer() {
        //Generate footer
        echo "&copy " . date("Y") . " Name here";
    }
```

As you see i have a copy icon and date, where it says "Name here" i want the user to edit this by calling `get_footer(text here);` This is located in my index.php while the function is located in the functions.php

Ex.
When user runs code: `get_footer("StackOverflow");`
The function would be:

```
function get_footer() {
        //Generate footer
        echo "&copy " . date("Y") . "StackOverflow";
    }
```

Which will output: `(c) 2013 Stackoverflow.`

Did i make it clear enough? If not, please tell me !

Regards
Stian

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: Also, the correct is `&copy;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:-

```
function get_footer($text) {
        //Generate footer
        echo "&copy " . date("Y") . " " . $text ;
    }

    get_footer("stackoverflow");
```